# StatusCodeResult not Logged to App Insights when 4xx

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

In my ASP.NET core 3.1 web api, I'm using the `ObjectResult StatusCode([ActionResultStatusCode] int statusCode, [ActionResultObjectValue] object value)` method from ControllerBase to return certain types of errors with a 422 status code.  In previous ASP.NET versions, throwing an exception with the status code information was standard and the logger would pick it up because it was an actual exception.  Now I have code like this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RequestSomething(RequestObject request)
{
  if(request.id == 0)
  {
    return StatusCode(422, "ID cannot be blank.");
  }
}
```

I was expecting to see something in app insights related to this, but there is nothing.  Ideally I would have the message as well, but at least a log of the error would be a good start!  I have requests, exceptions, dependency calls all showing up so I know it's hooked up and working.

I do not want to inject a logger everywhere and add a logging line before each of these.  How do I setup Application Insights to capture all 422 status code results when returned this way?

Comment: From the documentation "Older versions of the SDK do not support ASP.NET Core 3.X.". Is your Application Insights version up to date?

Comment: yes, I'm using the latest version.  thank you for the double check though!

Comment: @MPavlak, can you use visual studio to debug it? and make sure this line is actually executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are absolutely Correct. You don't need to inject the Logger in all the Controllers/ method. All you need to do the below.

1. Install Nuget Package (**Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore**)
2. Add **services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();** in your **ConfigureServices** method of Startup.
3. Link the App Service and Application Insights (which I think you have already done).

Below is how it looks in the App Insights.

my Code in ActionMethod is something similar to yours.

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
                return StatusCode(422, "ID cannot be blank or 1.");
        }
```

[image]

For others who are new to App Insights, You can learn how to integrate App insights with App Service at https://praveenkumarsreeram.com/2020/07/11/6-steps-to-integrate-application-insights-with-net-core-application-hosted-in-azure-app-service/

Comment: interesting.  that's how i expected it to work, but it does not work for me.  I guess I'll have to maybe start with a fresh project and do some testing / remove stuff from my project until this works and see what's breaking it.

Comment: Yeah. And, as you might, It's takes time  (2-5 mins) to reflect the telemetry in the portal.

Comment: yea, I usually have live stream on one tab and failures on another.  thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Yes. I follow the same too :-) Please accept if my answer make sense so that it helps others.

Comment: OK, so it's not the case that it's not collecting anything, just none of the 422 I was looking into were captured, but others were.  I verified no sampling is turned on so not sure why a bunch are missing and I don't see them on live stream when troubleshooting with a customer...  Also, the error message is not included.  How to include that in the log?  The message is always safe to capture so I'm not worried about sensitive data in there.

Comment: seems like this is working correctly.  the problem I was experiencing eventually ended up being a different service returning these errors and different AI instance where the errors were logged.  I believe to get the message logged, I need to use a TelemetryProcessor and look for 422 status code and add the message to the logs there.